# Scipy optimise minimise for 8 variables across > 1000 observations

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 7 | 25 |
| 16 | 9 | 23 |

Based on the values of x, y, z and 8 other unknown variables we can create a 'transformation column' which would be for example:

```
df['transformed_column'] = x * y * z * var_1 * var_2 * var_3 * ... * var_6 * var_7**2 / var_8 **2
```

The final transformation column is based on x, y, z and 8 other unknown variables and represents a percentage error value. The goal is to find the optimal values of these 8 unknown variables to reduce the sum of the transformation column as much as possible.

In reality this dataframe has > 1000 observations. The 8 unknown variables are made up of some angles measured in radians and some real numbers however all solutions should be real. No complex numbers.

So far I actually have it working however it is super slow and not producing great results.

```
def f(params):
    var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7, var_8 = params
    
    eqn = 0

    # here total_df is the dataframe that holds the x,y,z data
    for row in range(total_df.shape[0]):
        x = total_df.iloc[row]['x']
        y = total_df.iloc[row]['y']
        z = total_df.iloc[row]['z']
        eqn += x * y * z * var_1 * var_2 * var_3 * ... * var_6 * var_7**2 / var_8 **2
        
    eqn = (eqn / total_df.shape[0])**(1/2)
        
    return eqn


fun = f

x0 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] # starting points

bounds = [(-21, 21), (-21, 21), (-21, 21), (-20, 20), (-20, 20), (-20, 20), (60, 120), (60, 120), (-1, 0.5), (-1, 0.5)] #min/max values

 # function to ensure complex solutions are excluded
def con_real(t):
    return np.sum(np.iscomplex(t))

cons = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': con_real}]

res = minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)
```

As mentioned above this solution is too slow and does not provide accurate results. I am looking for a more optimised method please. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*In reality, the transformation is more complex and involves inverse matricies etc. Also, this is a non-linear transformation.*" -> we can't really comment on optimization problems when a dummy operation is given as example instead of the real one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot in this question that makes no sense. You can't decide whether you have eight or ten decision variables; I assume eight. I assume that your inner equation is

```
x * y * z * var_1 * var_2 * var_3 * var_4 * var_5 * var_6 * var_7**2 / var_8 **2
```

Vectorise; do as much as possible outside of the objective in a pre-processing step; and we get:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint

total_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': (14, 16),
    'y': ( 7,  9),
    'z': (25, 23),
})
xyz_coef = np.sqrt(total_df.prod(axis=1).sum() / total_df.shape[0])


def f(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    var_1_6 = params[:6].prod()
    var_7, var_8 = params[-2:]
    eqn = np.sqrt(var_1_6) * var_7 / var_8
    return eqn * xyz_coef


def always_real(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    radicand = params[:6].prod()
    return radicand


def regression_test() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    params = np.concatenate((
        rand.uniform(low=0, high=21, size=3),
        rand.uniform(low=0, high=20, size=3),
        rand.uniform(low=60, high=120, size=2),
        # rand.uniform(low=-1, high=0.5, size=2),  # these make no sense at all
    ))

    result = f(params)
    assert np.isclose(result, 3988.9807412068303, atol=1e-12, rtol=0)


def solve() -> np.ndarray:

    result = minimize(
        fun=f,
        x0=np.zeros(8),
        bounds=(
            (-21, 21), (-21, 21), (-21, 21),
            (-20, 20), (-20, 20), (-20, 20),
            (60, 120), (60, 120),
            # (-1, 0.5), (-1, 0.5),  # these make no sense and will be ignored
        ),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=always_real, lb=0, ub=np.inf,
        ),
    )
    assert result.success, result.message
    return result.x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    regression_test()
    print(solve())
```

Based on your bounds, the optimum is trivially one where all variables are zero save the last two which are 60.